# How to find dynamically allocated JMX port when port is 0

Tags: java, jmx

For a java application when jmx is enabled and the port is set 0, a port will be dynamically allocated:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0
```

What is the best way to find out what port is allocated?  I managed to find it out using ps and pfiles on Solaris, hoping there is a simpler why to find it (programmatically)

Also is there a better way to assign dynamic jmx ports to java applications on the same box and keep track of them?

Comment: Are you talking about remotely or locally?  I don't think there is a way to know remotely which port was allocated.  Are you talking from within the JVM or on the same OS but from another program?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344378/when-using-a-jmx-server-with-ephemeral-port-how-to-get-the-server-port-number/39400460)

```
String url = sun.management.ConnectorAddressLink.importRemoteFrom(0)
        .get("sun.management.JMXConnectorServer.0.remoteAddress");
String portStr = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("/jmxrmi"));      
int port = Integer.valueOf(portStr);
System.out.println(port);
```