# When using a JMX server with ephemeral port, how to get the server port number?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx, mbeans

When launching a Java application with these options:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
```

Java uses an ephemeral port, which is very useful to avoid collisions.

Is it possible to get the actual port (or connection URL) programmatically from within the application ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    String url = sun.management.ConnectorAddressLink.importRemoteFrom(0)
            .get("sun.management.JMXConnectorServer.0.remoteAddress");
    System.out.println(url);
```

This will print URL like

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:57025/jmxrmi
```