# Discovering JMX Ephemeral Port Number for Java 9+

Tags: java, jmx

This question: [When using a JMX server with ephemeral port, how to get the server port number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344378/when-using-a-jmx-server-with-ephemeral-port-how-to-get-the-server-port-number/39400460) indicates that we can use `sun.management.ConnectorAddressLink` with the params specified to discover the ephemeral JMX port (if we start our process with `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0`).

However for Java 9+, these classes were made private and can no longer be accessed. Is there any way one could programmatically find which port JMX has bound to?

Comment: This question was having a bounty + grace period and I posted an answer before bounty expired. I was hoping bounty will be awarded base don the submission date time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConnectorAddressLink class can be invoked via jdk.internal.agent module.

Below sample code shows how we can programmatically find JMX ephemeral port in java 9/11/14 (Tested with OpenJDK versions only).

***Java 9+ Code:***

In the below code you can get PID or use 0 to denote current PID hence providing a way to show JMX URL in both scenarios and they will be identical.

```
public class JMXEphemeralPortTest_JAVA9Plus {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String jmxURL = "NO JMX URL";
    String jmxURL2 = "NO JMX URL";
    if (isJava9Plus(System.getProperties())) {
      long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
      jmxURL = "From Java 9 Plus:-->" + importRemoteFrom_Java9Plus(Math.toIntExact(pid));
      jmxURL2 = "From Java 9 Plus:-->" + importRemoteFrom_Java9Plus(0);
    }
    System.out.println(jmxURL);
    System.out.println(jmxURL2);
  }
  private static boolean isJava9Plus(Properties properties) {
    double javaVersion = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("java.specification.version"));
    System.out.println("Java Version:"+javaVersion);
    return javaVersion >= 1.9;
  }
  private static String importRemoteFrom_Java9Plus(int pid) {
    try {
      final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("jdk.internal.agent.ConnectorAddressLink");
      final Method method = clazz.getMethod("importRemoteFrom", int.class);
      final Object instance = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
      Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) method.invoke(instance, pid);
      return map.get("sun.management.JMXConnectorServer.0.remoteAddress");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load needed java 9+ class", e);
    }
  }
}
```

***Java 9+ VM Arguments for the module and JMX**:

```
--add-modules jdk.management,jdk.management.agent
--add-exports=jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
```

***Java 9+ Result:***

Java Version:14.0
From Java 9 Plus:-->service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://XXXX:50678/jmxrmi
From Java 9 Plus:-->service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://XXXX:50678/jmxrmi

Java Version:9.0
From Java 9 Plus:-->service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://XXXX:60342/jmxrmi
From Java 9 Plus:-->service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://XXXX:60342/jmxrmi

Happy programming.